# How to set a dependent dropdown in excel, but ignore a number in source cell

Tags: excel, dropdown

For example:

I have a named range called "ABC". it's used as a 5 item dropdown list.

One cell B1 I have "ABC_1" typed. Not ABC.

I want cell B2 to reference named range ABC (even though ABC_1 is typed)

I know how to call the correct dropdown if the cell value matches the named range

From Data validation, select list, and use this formula:

`=INDIRECT(B1)`

How can I get it to ignore the final 2 characters always. Example:

if B1 value = "XXXX_1"
then 
in B2 call up dropdown for named range "XXXX"

or

if B1 value = "DDDD_2"
then 
in B2 call up dropdown for named range "DDDD"

I just need the final underscore, and number to always be ignored.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `LEFT` and `LEN` to drop the last underscore and number.

```
=INDIRECT(LEFT(B1, LEN(B1)-2))
```